# Consulta que calcule el estado segun otras tablas

Tags: php, mysql

Gracias por leerme, estoy usando Php y MySql, tengo en una tabla cuotas y en otra tabla los pagos de esas cuotas. ¿Como puedo saber que cuotas estan impagas y cual no?

TABLA_CUOTAS
id
importe
fechaVencimiento

PAGOS_EFECTIVO
idCuota
importe
fechaPago

PAGOS_CHEQUES
idCuota
importe
fechaPago

El tema es que las cuotas no tienen el estado "pago" o "impago", sino que se calcula haciendo las consultas a las otras tablas.

¿Puedo hacer todo esto en una sola consulta asi filtro por ejemplo, las cuotas pagas, las impagas y vencidas, etc?

Gracias!

Comment: Puedes hacer un `LEFT JOIN` entre las tablas, cuando no haya coincidencias la columna tomará el valor `NULL` y con eso sabrás si está pagada o no. Hay una dificultad en tu diseño, en vez de tener dos tablas para pagos, sería mejor tener una sola, agregando una columna que sea `tipo_pago` donde identificarías si el pago se hizo en efectivo o en cheque (o en otro futuro medio de pago como tarjeta de crédito, transferencia bancaria, etc). Y además no tendrías que hacer `JOIN`  con dos tablas para obtener el estado de todas las cuotas.

Answer (score 0):

El tipo de `JOIN` que sirve para mostrar las filas no coincidentes es `LEFT JOIN`. Cuando lo usas, las columnas no coincidentes adquieren el valor `NULL`. Luego puedes usar condicionales o `CASE` para mostrar otra cosa cuando el valor sea `NULL`.

Aparte de eso, hay un claro **error de diseño en tus datos**. ¿Por qué en vez de tener dos tablas para manejar los pagos no usas una sola con una columna que identifique el *tipo de pago* (por ejemplo: `1` para pago en efectivo; `2` para cheque, etc).

Esto permite tener la información más centralizada. Si quieres tener todo en un solo resultado ahora mismo tendrías que hacer `JOIN` entre tres tablas en vez de dos y esto tiene su coste en rendimiento. Además, ¿qué pasa si el sistema evoluciona y se agregan otros tipos de pago como transferencia bancaria, tarjeta de crédito, etc? Usar una tabla por cada tipo de pago no hace otra cosa que dispersar los datos y complicar el mantenimiento/integridad de los mismos.

O, vamos a complicarlo un poco más. ¿Qué tal si el sistema evoluciona y se permiten hacer pagos fraccionados o algo así como abonos a la cuota total pendiente?

Veamos un ejemplo aplicando lo dicho, basándonos en datos de prueba. Con con la consulta respondo también a tu otra duda: compararemos la `fecha_vencimiento` con `NOW()` para determinar si se venció o no la fecha de pago.

Espero te sea de utilidad:

#### Datos de prueba completos

**<kbd>[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/CFZJS55195)</kbd>**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cuotas 
(
    cuota_id            INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    importe             DECIMAL(10,2),
    fecha_vencimiento   DATETIME
 )ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO cuotas (importe,fecha_vencimiento) 
    VALUES
    (1000.00,'2018-09-20'),
    (5000.00,'2018-08-20'),
    (8000.00,'2018-09-21'),
    (2000.00,'2018-09-28'),
    (1500.00,'2018-12-25');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pagos 
(
    cuota_id            INT NOT NULL,
    tipo_id             INT NOT NULL,  -- por esta columna identificamos el tipo de pago: 1. Efectivo, 2. Cheque
    importe             DECIMAL(10,2),
    fecha_pago          DATETIME,
    CONSTRAINT pagos_PKA01 UNIQUE (cuota_id,fecha_pago),
    FOREIGN KEY (cuota_id) REFERENCES cuotas(cuota_id) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE  CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO pagos (cuota_id,tipo_id,importe,fecha_pago) 
    VALUES
    (1,1,1000.00,'2018-09-11'),
    (4,2,2000.00,'2018-09-11');
```

#### Consulta

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN p.fecha_pago IS NULL THEN 'Por pagar' 
        ELSE p.fecha_pago
     END AS status_pago,       
    CASE
        WHEN c.fecha_vencimiento < NOW() AND p.importe IS NULL THEN 'Vencido' 
        ELSE 'No-Vencido'
     END AS status_fecha,
    p.importe,
    p.tipo_id,
    c.fecha_vencimiento        
FROM cuotas c 
    LEFT JOIN pagos p ON c.cuota_id=p.cuota_id
;
```

#### Resultados:

```
status_pago     status_fecha    importe    tipo_id      fecha_vencimiento
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-09-11      No-Vencido      1000,00    1                20.09.2018
2018-09-11      No-Vencido      2000,00    2                28.09.2018
Por pagar       Vencido         NULL       NULL             20.08.2018
Por pagar       No-Vencido      NULL       NULL             21.09.2018
Por pagar       No-Vencido      NULL       NULL             25.12.2018
```

#### Post-Data

Debo decir que todavía hay varias asignaturas pendientes por definir en tu modelo. Por ejemplo, ¿cómo determinar los pagos que se realizaron, pero después de haber sobrepasado la fecha de vencimiento, o sea, qué pagos se hicieron ya vencidos?  Y así, otras situaciones extrañas que se pueden presentar y que habría que controlar/recopilar.

Quiero decir que un modelo de datos debe hacerse pensando incluso en aquello que no se te ha pedido, pero que se te puede pedir en un futuro. Si el diseño está bien, responderá con facilidad a casi todo, si no está bien, vas a tener que modificarlo para satisfacer futuros requerimientos y a veces se paga un alto precio cuando hay que re-estructurar estando los datos ya en producción.